# SQL query: Current lowest price of products

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggeling with a SQL query for a project.

The following tables are given:

```
tblProduct => (proProductID, proProductName)
tblSeller => (selSellerID, selSellerName)
linkProductSeller => (linkID, linkProductID, linkSellerID, linkPrice, linkShippingPrice, linkDatetime)
```

Each time a price/shipping price of a product changes at a seller a new row in linkProductSeller is added.

**I need to know the current lowest price/shipping price combination and seller for a product.**

To get all current prices of a product I use this query

```
SELECT linkProductID, linkSellerID, linkPrice+linkShippingPrice as price, linkDatetime
FROM linkProductSeller AS a
WHERE linkDatetime = (
    SELECT MAX(linkDatetime)
    FROM linkProductSeller AS b
    WHERE a.linkProductID = b.linkProductID
AND a.linkSellerID = b.linkSellerID)
ORDER BY linkProductID ASC, price ASC, linkDatetime DESC
```

Thx for your support.

Comment: Change your order by clause to sort by price ASC and the first row retrieved should be the lowest price

Comment: Thx but **I need only the lowest price for each product**.

Comment: You would need to use a subselect from what I can tell. Have a look at this question and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228577/get-the-minimum-price-of-each-product-type-with-currency-conversion?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data you need is in linkProductSeller so this should work

```
select l.linkProductId, min(linkPrice + linkShippingPrice) as minPrice
  from linkProductSeller l,
       (select linkProductID, linkSellerId, max(linkDateTime) as linkDateTime
          from linkProductSeller 
         group by linkProductID, linkSellerId) m
 where l.linkProductID = m.linkProductID
   and l.linkSellerID = m.linkSellerID
   and l.linkDateTime = m.linkDateTime
 group by linkProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is not fully correct, I guess. If you need names of products and sellers, and it doesn't matter when precisely the prices were changed (you need just the current ones), then, I think, you'll need something like this:

```
select 
    p.proProductID, 
    p.proProductName, 
    s.selSellerID, 
    s.selSellerName, 
    min(l.linkPrice + l.linkShippingPrice) as Price
  from 
    tblProduct p,
    tblSeller s,
    (select * from linkProductSeller 
    where (linkProductID, linkSellerID, linkDateTime) 
    in 
        (select linkProductID, linkSellerID, max(linkDateTime) from linkProductSeller 
        group by linkProductID, linkSellerID 
        having linkDateTime = max(linkDateTime)) l
where 
    p.proProductID= l.linkProductID
    and s.selSellerID= m.linkSellerID
group by 
    p.proProductID, 
    p.proProductName, 
    s.selSellerID, 
    s.selSellerName
```

Comment: That is correct. Two more joins are needed but to simplify I left that out.